# Regular map in Projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This may be simple but I got confusion. I am just reading myself about the regular map in Projective variety. It says $f$ is regular at a point $p$ in $X$ if $f = g/h$, where $g, h$ homogenous in $k[x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}]$ of same degree and $h \neq 0$ for some neighbourhood $U$ of $P.$ The problem is in definition it says even if $g$ and $h$ are not the function the quotient is well-defined. How is that makes sense? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $d=\deg(g)=\deg(h)$ and $p=[x]$ for some homogeneous coordinates $x$, then $g(\lambda x) = \lambda^d g(x)$ shows that $g(x)$ doesn't depend only on $p$, but $g(\lambda x)/h(\lambda x) = g(x)/h(x)$ shows that $g(x)/h(x)$ does.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I got it.